# How do I construct a new array of object with some deleted properties from another array of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects, I want to construct a new array from an old array, without some of properties from the old array.

For example I have an array of objects like this

```js
 [
       {
            "userImages": [
                "url to image here"
            ],
            "likes": [
                {
                    "userImages": [
                       "url to image here"
                    ],
                    "likes": [
                        "5ea708a40c244528c0e076c8"
                    ],
                    "_id": "5ea708a40c244528c0e076c8",
                    "name": "Lee",
                    "gender": "male"
                }
            ],
            "_id": "5ec95161fc8ed82bc4d66279",
            "gender": "male",
            "name": "Aahan Aarav"
        },
        {
            "userImages": [
                "url to image"
            ],
            "likes": [
                {
                    "userImages": [
                       "url to image here"
                    ],
                    "likes": [
                        "5ec95161fc8ed82bc4d66279",
                    ],
                    "_id": "5ea708a40c244528c0e076c8",
                    "name": "Lee",
                    "gender": "male"
                }
            ],
            "_id": "5ec95161fc8ed82bc4d66277",
            "gender": "female",
            "name": "Rajiv Rakesh"
        }
   ]
```

Please how do I construct a new array with the same properties as above but without the likes array: eg just like the below:

```js
 [
       {
            "userImages": [
                "url to image here"
            ],
            "_id": "5ec95161fc8ed82bc4d66279",
            "gender": "male",
            "name": "Aahan Aarav"
        },
        {
            "userImages": [
                "https://tieinupuserinfopictures.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/1589642272641-pexels-photo-1372134.jpeg"
            ],
              "_id": "5ec95161fc8ed82bc4d66277",
            "gender": "female",
            "name": "Rajiv Rakesh"
        }
   ]
```

Comment: HI Ossy, this is fairly simple to do with `.map`. Have you tried putting any code together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a modern environment (directly or via transpilation), you can use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with destructuring and object literals to easily pick out the properties you want and create new objects with them, perhaps with an arrow function:

```
const result = original.map(
//   vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv−−− destructuring to pick out the desired props
    ({userImages, _id, gender, name}) => ({userImages, _id, gender, name})
// Object literal with shorthand props−−−−^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
);
```

Live Example:

```js
const original = [
       {
            "userImages": [
                "url to image here"
            ],
            "likes": [
                {
                    "userImages": [
                       "url to image here"
                    ],
                    "likes": [
                        "5ea708a40c244528c0e076c8"
                    ],
                    "_id": "5ea708a40c244528c0e076c8",
                    "name": "Lee",
                    "gender": "male"
                }
            ],
            "_id": "5ec95161fc8ed82bc4d66279",
            "gender": "male",
            "name": "Aahan Aarav"
        },
        {
            "userImages": [
                "url to image"
            ],
            "likes": [
                {
                    "userImages": [
                       "url to image here"
                    ],
                    "likes": [
                        "5ec95161fc8ed82bc4d66279",
                    ],
                    "_id": "5ea708a40c244528c0e076c8",
                    "name": "Lee",
                    "gender": "male"
                }
            ],
            "_id": "5ec95161fc8ed82bc4d66277",
            "gender": "female",
            "name": "Rajiv Rakesh"
        }
   ];

const result = original.map(({userImages, _id, gender, name}) => ({userImages, _id, gender, name}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
    max-height: 100% !important;
}
```